# Extract all words between two specific words in a character vector

Tags: regex, string, r

Is there a more efficient method? How can I do this without `stringr`?

```
txt <- "I want to extract the words between this and that, this goes with that, this is a long way from that"

library(stringr)
w_start <- "this"
w_end <- "that"
pattern <- paste0(w_start, "(.*?)", w_end)
wordsbetween <- unlist(str_extract_all(txt, pattern))
gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", str_sub(wordsbetween, nchar(w_start)+1, -nchar(w_end)-1))
[1] "and"                "goes with"          "is a long way from"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an approach I use in qdap:

**Using qdap:**

```
library(qdap)
genXtract(txt, "this", "that")

## > genXtract(txt, "this", "that")
##         this  :  that1         this  :  that2         this  :  that3 
##                " and "          " goes with " " is a long way from "
```

**Without an add on package:**

```
regmatches(txt, gregexpr("(?<=this).*?(?=that)", txt, perl=TRUE))

## > regmatches(txt, gregexpr("(?<=this).*?(?=that)", txt, perl=TRUE))
## [[1]]
## [1] " and "                " goes with "          " is a long way from "
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought you'd have something like this up your sleeve!

Comment: May I ask, out of curiosity, what are you using that outputs the `##` before each line? I see that a bit here at SO but have no idea what's producing it.

Comment: I have a homemade function in my .Rprofile to insert `## ` in front of the output and copy to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another rough attempt using `strsplit`, though it can probably be refined further:

```
txtspl <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("[[:punct:]]","",txt),"this|that"))
txtspl[txtspl!=" "][-1]

#[1] " and "                " goes with "          " is a long way from "
```